# Java/Android: how rewrite more efficient this interface?

Tags: java, android

I need to receive some data via `JSON`, and I'm using `Volley`, with a `Callback`.

Data could be a simple string or a `JSONArray`.

Is it possibile to rewrite in only one generic method?

```
public interface BaseMapper {

    final static String API_URL_LOGIN = "/apiv2/account";
    final static String API_URL_CAMPAIGN = "/apiv2/campaign";
    final static String API_URL_SEARCH_CARD ="/apiv2/member-card?card=";

    public interface VolleyCallbackArray {

        void onSuccess(JSONArray array);

    }

    public interface VolleyCallbackString {

        void onSuccess(String string);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VolleyCallbackArray` and `VolleyCallbackString` could be replaced by a single generic:

```
public interface VolleyCallback<T> {
    void onSuccess(T result);
}
```

Then you specify `T` at time of implementing:

```
public class A implements BaseMapper.VolleyCallback<JSONArray> {
    public void onSuccess(JSONArray result){
    }
}

public class B implements BaseMapper.VolleyCallback<String> {
    public void onSuccess(String result){
    }
}
```